# Appium - Perform Multitouch gesture

Tags: android, appium, multi-touch

I want to perform a multitouch gesture with Appium on an Android Device using the example app `MultiTouchTester`.
I am using JUnit and therefore my test case is implemented in Java.

I want to perform an long press (tap) by three fingers. Afterwards each finger has to move to a specific direction. This is what I have so far but it does not work as expected:

```
MultiTouchAction mta = new MultiTouchAction(driver);
TouchAction ta0 = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(200, 800, 1000).moveTo(200, 100).release();
TouchAction ta1 = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(500, 800, 1000).moveTo(500, 1600).release();
TouchAction ta2 = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(900, 800, 1000).moveTo(100, 800).release();
mta.add(ta0).add(ta1).add(ta2).perform();
```

So originally I want to perform a slow swipe by three fingers. Each finger has to move to a differen position and I want to see the current movement of each finger (therefore `longPress()`).

What I get is an extreme fast multitouch gesture without any hint if it has been performed correct or not...

Has anyone a hint?

Greets.

Comment: how do you want to verify the correctness of the gesture?
also could you try increasing the time to 3-4 sec for longPress and include your observation.

Comment: Verification by seeing. I don't want to know if the actions hit exactly the specified points but I want to see the taps moving around in the app. At the moment the longPress duration is 1 sec. But when I execute it is about 10 ms. So I think there is a fault anywhere and now I am looking for a workaround for this issue.